# How To Deal With Asynchronous Login to REST API?

Tags: android, api, rest, networking, authentication

I'm trying to write the login portion of my android app that authenticates with my REST API. This is what I have currently

**LogInTask boolean function**

```
   boolean LogInTask(String username, String password){



    AuthOrNot.setCurrent(true);
    Log.wtf("START", "" + AuthOrNot.getCurrent());

    UserAPI.Factory.getInstance().authenticateUser("testuser", "password").enqueue(new Callback<TokenJSON>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TokenJSON> call, Response<TokenJSON> response) {

            try{
                String token = response.body().getToken();
                Log.wtf("WORKS",""+ token);

                AuthOrNot.setCurrent(false);

                Log.wtf("AUTH", "" + AuthOrNot.getCurrent());


            }catch (NullPointerException t){
                Log.wtf("NO", "Didn't work, most likely incorrect username+password");
                AuthOrNot.setCurrent(false);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TokenJSON> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.wtf("FAIL",""+t.getMessage());
            AuthOrNot.setCurrent(false);
        }
    });

    Log.wtf("AUTH", "" + AuthOrNot.getCurrent());

    return AuthOrNot.getCurrent();
}
```

I know this is probably not the best way to go about making this, which is why I am here now. What is happening is that the network request takes 1-2 seconds, by which time the code is already at the bottom, and AuthoOrNot.getCurrent() == true, which means that the next activity is launched whether or not the username+password combo is correct.

Comment: Create a listener to get fired at the end of onresponse. In the callback do the cehck and go to the other activity

Comment: What kind of listener would should this be, one of the built-in methods or should I create my own? Also, where exactly is the 'callback'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an interface to use it as a callback. The interface may look like this:

```
public Interface LoginCallback{
    void onLoginSuccess();
    void onLoginFailure();
}
```

Then update your code to something like this:

```
void LogInTask(String username, String password, final LoginCallback callback){
// this isnt't needed: AuthOrNot.setCurrent(true);
//Log.wtf("START", "" + AuthOrNot.getCurrent());

UserAPI.Factory.getInstance().authenticateUser("testuser", "password").enqueue(new Callback<TokenJSON>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<TokenJSON> call, Response<TokenJSON> response) {

        try{
            String token = response.body().getToken();
            Log.wtf("WORKS",""+ token);

            callback.onLoginSuccess();

            //Log.wtf("AUTH", "" + AuthOrNot.getCurrent());


        }catch (NullPointerException t){
            Log.wtf("NO", "Didn't work, most likely incorrect username+password");
            callback.onLoginFailure();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TokenJSON> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.wtf("FAIL",""+t.getMessage());
        callback.onLoginFailure();
    }
});

//Log.wtf("AUTH", "" + AuthOrNot.getCurrent());

//nothing to return;
}
```

Then wherever you are calling the LogInTask method:

```
LoginTask("user", "password", new LoginCallback() {
    void onLoginSuccess(){
    //at this point you are logged in
    }
    void onLoginFailure(){
    //at this point the login has failed
    }
});
```

P.S: method names should start in lower case, so "LoginTask()" should actually be "loginTask()"

Comment: Would I need to add a callback as a third parameter of the LogInTask method?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant to add it, but forgot. I will edit my answer.

Comment: No worries! Everything is working now thank you so much. I will mark 'answered'

Comment: Oh no worries I had figured it out which was why I removed the comment. I should have made a note saying that, my bad! Thank you though

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment to Daniel Chiriac's answer, but since I don't have the reputation to comment:

Since you *have* to override onResponse method defined in the retrofit2 Callback class you cannot change the method signature by adding another paramter.

I would use "callback" as method paramter for the LoginTask method instead.

Edit: Has been corrected now :)

Also the class definition can be found here: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html

Comment: Yes, I meant to add it there. Didn't realise I had added it to the wrong method. Good spot.